# Given a string of adjacent sides of a die, determine the opposite side of each side

Tags: combinatorics

A total of $N-1$ actions are performed on a 6-sided die, each one representing a 90-degree rotation of the die whose axis is unknown. Each time, the number on the topside of the die is written down, hence there's a string of N numbers (the first number being the one before the first action taking place). Now my problem is, given one such string of N numbers where each consecutive two represent the numbers produced on the topside of the die by a 90-degree rotation, is there a way to determine the opposite side of each number, or proving that there does not exist such a solution?

Comment: For standard dice, opposite sides add to 7.

Comment: I suppose we don't know that the die is has a standard layout (with the number of eyes on opposite sides summing to seven)? Have you actually sat down and tried to solve such a puzzle, given some string of length $N$?

Comment: @Lovsovs I just assumed that much was obvious, yes, it doesn't follow the standard layout. And yes, I have tried to solve it, but I can't get a good start, and that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Surely it occurred to you that the string of $N$ values (of whatever kind) might be either inconsistent (so no solution could exist) or inadequate to uniquely determine a solution (perhaps because the die kept getting switched between fewer than six top sides).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to fill out the adjacency matrix of the die, which is a (symmetric) matrix that has a $1$ in its $ij$th entry if side $i$ and $j$ are adjacent to each other on the die (i.e. you can get from $i$ to $j$ by doing a single 90 degree rotation), and a $0$ otherwise (put $0$s on the diagonal as well).

**Here's how to do it:**
For each pair of consecutive numbers $\{i,j\}$ in your list, put a $1$ in the $ij$th entry of adjecency matrix. If you find that some row has more than four $1$s in it, the die is inconsistent (side $i$ should have a $0$ exactly for the connection with itself and side opposite to it) and you can stop. Otherwise keep going until either the adjacency matrix is filled (and every row has two $0$s and four $1$s) or your list ends (it could be that the list doesn't contain enough information to construct the layout of the die).

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you very much!

Comment: @FuriousMathematician Glad to be of help :)